# mkdir(/Debug-iphoneos, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO): Read-only file system (30) error on Xcode 13.2 beta

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode13

I'm trying to build my app on `Xcode 13.2 beta`.

Getting this error: `mkdir(/Debug-iphoneos, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO): Read-only file system (30)` error.

And for the solve I tried give write permission to folders but it is not working. Any help?